# Readability of stacking inequalities

Tags: soft-question, notation

I have an expression similar to
\begin{align}
f(x)\ge 0 \quad \text{for }g(x)\ge 0\\
f(x)=0 \quad \text{for }g(x)=0
\end{align}
I think I've seen some people condense equations similar to the above as
\begin{align}
f(x)\substack{\ge\\(=)} 0 \quad \text{for }g(x)\substack{\ge\\(=)} 0\\
\end{align}

Is this well-accepted and readable? Or should I write out the details of the $\ge$ case and just say similarly for the $=$ case? Unfortunately the expressions in my case are pretty large, making it pretty verbose to include both cases explicitly.

Comment: The second one is not so readable.

Comment: Not widely used. Could confuse. I don't see a reason to condense this as writing it out in full is not much more effort here and avoids any misunderstandings. If you use it then you should define it so that any reader that doesn't understand it can find an explanation of the notation in the text.

Comment: For lecturing/presentations I think it is okay, provided you make an effort to explain it. I am not a big fan of the stacking version for writing. Even something clumsy like "If $g(x) \geq 0$ ($= 0$) then $f(x) \geq 0$ ($=0$)" would be better in my opinion. At the very least I have seen this formulation regularly (if not frequently) in papers/textbooks. I would also advocate, for clarity, writing further instead "If $g(x)$ is non-negative (zero) then $f(x)$ is non-negative (zero)" so the parenthetical doesn't get confused as part of the notation.

Answer (score 0):

you could just use:

$$f(x)\begin {cases}g(x)\ge0, \ge 0\\g(x)=0, 0\end {cases}$$

or something similar. this uses \begin {cases}

edit:

or as the comments below this answer show $f(x)=\begin {cases}\ge0, \text{ if } g(x)\ge0\\0,\text{ if }g(x)=0\end {cases}$

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a conventional notation. It's really hard to understand for me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise  I'll admit I messed it up a bit, but it should be more like:
$$f(x)=\begin {cases}\ge 0,\text{if }g(x)\ge0\\0, \text {if }g(x)=0\end {cases}$$

Comment: You mean $$f(x)\begin{cases}\ge0&\mbox{if} \ g(x)\ge0 \\ =0&\mbox{if} \ g(x)=0\end{cases}$$? For me it is not "typographically" good, but atleast it's comprehensible. :)

Comment: to me other than the equals sign and the rearrangement of the conclusion and premise it's still close to the true notation.  do you want me to fix the answer ?

Comment: No, I'm noone to tell you to change your answer. :) It's just my opinion on the beauty of notations.

Comment: if this wasn't a soft-question tagged question it could be your right to.

Comment: I prefer OP's option 1, find the OP's option 2 hard to read & understand, and I also dislike the \cases solutions in the comments, for the same reasons.